# How to set API data into an array using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am storing API data into an array using useState Hook. When the data is render first time I am getting an empty array and after the first render I am able to get data.

Actually, I am try to create a dynamic select dropdown based on the number data row in the database.

```js
const Groups = () => {
  const [userList, setUserList] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://localhost:44316/api/auth/getavailableusers",
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          credentials: "include",
        }
      );
      const content = await response.json();
      setUserList(content);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <select id="multiselectDropdown" multiple>
        {userList.content.map((user) => (
          <option value={user.userId}>{user.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

because of first render is empty I am getting undefined error.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox?

Comment: You should set a default value to `userList` state to avoid errors. `useState({ content: []})` should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign empty array to **userList**

```
  const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
```

and try to use null check to avoid issues

```
<select id="multiselectDropdown" multiple>
        {userList.length > 0 && 
         userList?.content?.map((user) => (
          <option value={user.userId}>{user.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't render if you don't have the info yet. You should just make sure the API has returned with a value & check it like this:

```
{userList.content.length > 0 ? 
<select>
...
</select>
: null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing this code

```
{userList.content.map(...)
```

to

```
{userList.content?.map(...)
```

should work.